# Finding least squares-functional of two vectors

Tags: matlab, optimization, linear-algebra

Say I have two column vectors of same size: P and Q. What I need to do is find the least squares-functional distance `D = ||P - Q||^2`. What does this mean and how do I implement it in matlab. Should I use the `norm()` function?

Comment: Yes [`norm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html)`(P-Q)` returns `||P - Q||`. Then `D = norm(P-Q)^2`

Comment: Depending on the problem, `D` is normally the *squared* distance, and that "square" is normally included to save you from having to do a square-root.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
norm(P-Q)^2
```

or

```
sum((P-Q).^2)
```

A small test:

```
P = randn(1e7,1);
Q = randn(1e7,1);

tic
norm(P-Q)^2;
toc

tic
sum((P-Q).^2);
toc
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 0.130086 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.098494 seconds.
```

So manually squaring and summing is a tad faster, and perhaps more intuitive.

Comment: Gee, that's quite a difference. I wonder what could possibly be the reason for this.

Comment: +1 might be worth noting the small numerical difference in the results of the two methods as well.

Comment: @EitanT: `norm` strips away the signs of all components before raising them to a power (2 in the case of 2-norm). Then it raises the sum to a power (1/2 for the 2-norm), which you then "square away" again...so there's a few avoidable losses there, which you avoid by the second solution.

Comment: @wakjah: true. In most languages, `sqrt` generally uses a different algorithm than `^(1./2.)` (the one `norm` uses), there could indeed be small differences (but only The Mathworks knows this for sure of course :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis You really think that the additional rooting and squaring is the reason for this difference?

Comment: @EitanT: Yes, partially. Of course there's also some overhead of checking user inputs etc., but I think the rooting-and-squaring is the major component. Note also that `norm` uses exponentiation (`^(1/2)`) rather than square root, which could give rise to a difference as well (although I suspect optimizations to be in place for the 2-norm....) Anyway, without access to the actual implementation of `norm`, we're just taking shots in the dark here :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) indeed defines the 2-norm with `^(1/2)`, but we can't really know whether it is actually implemented this way...

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to find the square of the Euclidian norm, or in other words `sum((P(i) - Q(i))^2)`, then you can use `sumsqr(P - Q)`.

**EDIT**: The Euclidian norm is defined as the square root of the sum of the squares, so in your case it would be `sqrt(sum((P(i) - Q(i))^2))`. That is what `||P - Q||` means. So `||P - Q||^2` would just be the sum of the squares of `(P - Q)`, and MATLAB has a built-in function for that, as stated above.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I suppose I have just always had that toolbox. It is also in Octave for free.